# Add HTML Snippet to Wordpress Blog Page?

Tags: wordpress

I have recently started working with Wordpress, and I use the HTML Snippets plug-in to fill in the contents of each page. This works well until I hit the blog page. My blog page does not take anything from the page editor, so I can neither paste code snippets nor write anything in the WP page editor field. It only responds to posts. As a result, I am unable to add anything static to my blog page. Also, editing the template post_list file also leads to damaging the template.

How do I go about adding static elements to my blog page?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to add 'dynamic' content to your blog page? You can add 'static' content by amending the code in the index.php file of the template you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially it sounds like you're wanting to add a page template to your theme, which you can then assign as your 'Posts' page through the Wordpress admin.

The question itself is rather too broad to answer without an attempt at coding it yourself, but you can read more about it on the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Creating_a_Page_Template